# How to get values from one windows app form to another form in a different project using WCF?

Tags: c#, forms, wcf

I have no background in WCF yet so what I have done so far is based only in research. What I am trying to do is this.

I created a solution with **three** projects. Two Windows Form Applications and one WCF Service Application.

In form 1, there is a textbox and a button. If update button is clicked, whatever the value in the textbox should be reflected in the other form if refresh button is clicked. Here is what I have done so far:

**ISimulatorService.cs**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISimulatorService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void SetSerialNumber(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    int GetSerialNumber();
}
```

**ISimulatorService.svc**

```
 public class Service1 : ISimulatorService
 {
    public int serial;
    public string modelName;

    public void SetSerialNumber(int value)
    {
        this.serial = value;
    }

    public int GetSerialNumber()
    {
        return serial;
    }
 }
```

Update button in **Form1**

```
 private void btn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference.SimulatorServiceClient client = new ServiceReference.SimulatorServiceClient();
        try
        {
            client.Open();
            client.SetSerialNumber(Convert.ToInt32(txt_serialnumber.Text));                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (client.State == System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Opened)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Communication Closed");
                client.Close();
            }
        }

    }
```

Refresh button in **Form 2**

```
private void btn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference.SimulatorServiceClient client = new ServiceReference.SimulatorServiceClient();
        txt_serialnumber.Text = client.GetSerialNumber().ToString();
    }
```

The return value is always zero. What should I implement to store a value so I can retrieve that value in the other form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `serial` variable is not persited between calls. The service will be activated the first time when you call `SetSerialNumber` then closed, and it will be activated a second time when you call `GetSerialNumber` then closed again. In short therms, it will be two different instances, therefore you need something to persist the data beetween calls. You have two cases :

**You don't need the data to persisted on disk**, then use something like [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx). Here is a short snippet :

```
public class Service1 : ISimulatorService
{
    private ObjectCache _cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    private CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();

    public void SetSerialNumber(int value)
    {
        _cache.Set("serial", value, policy);
    }

    public int GetSerialNumber()
    {
        (int)_chache["serial"];
    }
 }
```

**You need the data to be peristed on disk**, then [use a database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090(v=vs.110).aspx).